# last 10 digits of sum in given series

Tags: java, biginteger

Input contains an integer N

the series looks like this

[image]

This is a problem from hackerrank my code passed all test cases except one it is timeout actually help is appreciated

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.text.*;
import java.math.*;
import java.util.regex.*;
 public class Solution {
     public static BigInteger calculateSelfPowers(){
         Scanner z = new Scanner(System.in);
         int num = z.nextInt();
         BigInteger modval = BigInteger.valueOf(10).pow(10);
         BigInteger sum = BigInteger.ZERO;
         for (int i = 1; i <= num; i++)
         sum = sum.add(BigInteger.valueOf(i).modPow(BigInteger.valueOf(i), modval)).mod(modval);
         return sum;
     }
     public static void main(String[] args){
         System.out.println(calculateSelfPowers());
     }

 }
```

here is link for problem in hackerrank [linkhere](https://www.hackerrank.com/contests/projecteuler/challenges/euler048)

Comment: It looks like you're computing the value if i^i each time and taking the last 10 digits. However, if i is large, this will still take forever. You need to find a better way to compute the last 10 digits of i^i without computing the entirety of i^i

Comment: i passed every test case except one that too that is timeout i need a better algorithm to do this any ideas

Comment: @barrycarter: modPow should reduce that time considerably by using mod everywhere, so the numbers used remain in the range defined by modval. So it will not actually calculate the full i^i and then do a mod, also on intermediate values in the algorithm, mod is used. It should be pretty efficient.

Comment: Could it be that you get a timeout because you don't enter a number?

Answer (score 1):

You can improve your code by taking `mod()` out of the loop and by calling `BigInteger.valueOf(i)` only once. Addition is cheap (fast), while `mod()` isn't. The final sum is probably 16 or 17 digits, but you can `mod()` that once to get the same result as the constant reduction by `mod()` in your code.

This simple example (I removed the scanner and took the highest number allowed, `999999`) runs in only 4 seconds on my system:

```
package modpowtest;

import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.text.*;
import java.math.*;

public class ModPowTest 
{
    public static BigInteger calculateSelfPowers()
    {
        int num = 999999;
        BigInteger modval = BigInteger.valueOf(10).pow(10);
        BigInteger sum = BigInteger.ZERO;
        for (int i = 1; i <= num; i++)
        {
            BigInteger bi = BigInteger.valueOf(i); 
            sum = sum.add(bi.modPow(bi, modval));
        }
        return sum.mod(modval);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        System.out.println(calculateSelfPowers());
    }

}
```

You just have to add the `Scanner` stuff again and rename to `Solution`.

If I use `num = 10;`, I get the same solution as they do.

Comment: thats a time out too..any way thanks for your time rudy.

Comment: 4 seconds are a timeout for you? Do you actually enter a number when your code is running?

Comment: thats a hackerrank question it will automatically enters inputs